# Why define BackboneJS Models & Views in jQuery on load and connecting it to the window object?

Tags: backbone.js

I see many tutorials initializing Backbone Models/Views after jQuery loaded. Why is that? Can't you define it before?

For example **[link](http://adamjspooner.github.com/coffeescript-meet-backbonejs/02/docs/script.html)**

```
jQuery ->

  class ListView extends Backbone.View

    el: $ 'body'

    initialize: ->
      _.bindAll @
      @counter = 0
      @render()
```

You could define the classes before document loads and initialize views/models after document loads?

---

Also I see Models/Views defined under `window` why is that?

```
window.TodoView = Backbone.View.extend
  ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Why initialize a View after jQuery?**

From the [main Backbone page](http://backbonejs.org/);

> Backbone's only hard dependency is Underscore.js ( > 1.3.1). For RESTful persistence, history support via Backbone.Router and **DOM manipulation with Backbone.View**, include json2.js, and either **jQuery** (> 1.4.2) or Zepto.

[Emphasis mine]

So that's the dependency right there.

**Models/Views defined under `window`?**

It simplifies these little tutorial examples - everything has access to `window`, so it makes a useful (if messy) dumping ground for globals (ctors, variables, functions, etc).

IMO, for larger (non-demo) projects, you should be using something like [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/).

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure, it is done for the sake of simplicity. Of course, you can (and probably should) define your constructors outside `jQuery(document).ready()`. And also you can (and again probably should) use one your own global object in order to not pollute the global space.